# Call a c++ method that returns a string, from c#

Tags: c#, c++, string

Please help,

```
my c++ function:
extern "C" REGISTRATION_API void calculate(char* msg)
{
//some calculation here

msg = "some text"; 
}
```

my c# call:

```
[DllImport("thecpp.dll")]
static extern void calculate(StringBuilder sMsg);

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
            calculate(msg);
            MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString());
        }
```

No matter what i put in msg, the stringbuilder is always empty? why? whats wrong? any ideas? please share

Comment: Your C++ function is a memory leak.

Comment: In your C code, you're assigning a value to the `msg` pointer itself, not to the memory pointed to. I don't know how to fix this w.r.t. marshalling, but I'm just throwing it out here because two answers seem to have missed it already.

Comment: @SLaks: It's not a memory leak, but I'll admit that it's scary assigning a string literal to a pointer to non-const `char`.

Comment: So, what are the suggestions? how to fix this? thanks

Comment: @SLaks: It's not a memory leak (only if you use new, malloc, or a similar function), but the C# buffer will be unchanged.  He needs to change what's contained at the memory address that is passed in, changing his local variable to a different memory address won't have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you should use `string` for `LPCTSTR` buffers and `StringBuilder` for `LPTSTR` buffers.

But you need 2 changes:

1) Set the capacity on your StringBuilder
2) You should be doing `strcpy` into that buffer, changing what memory address that variable holds won't do anything as you have it now.  You need to change what is at the memory address.

So you want in your C/C++ code:

```
extern "C" REGISTRATION_API void calculate(LPSTR msg)
{
    //Also consider refactoring this function to take in the buffer length
    strcpy(msg, "some text");
}
```

and in C#:

```
[DllImport("thecpp.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void calculate(StringBuilder sMsg);

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder(1024);
    calculate(msg);
    MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString());
}
```

Note: You really should pass in the length of the buffer that you are passing in to the calculate function as well.

Comment: can u please give me an example

Comment: @Zee99: Try what I gave you above.

Comment: The StringBuilder constructor call is wrong.  That should be 666.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a bit hazy on the syntax, but I believe you want something like:

```
[DllImport("thecpp.dll")] static extern void calculate([in, out] StringBuilder sMsg);
```

Comment: nope, i added the in/out, still no answer from the stringbuilder